# React, Typescript, d3js, Getting a No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I have found a error Typescript is throwing when using the scaleLinear() function from d3js and wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of solving this problem. The code is built in react and is using typescript. Here is the source code:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { select, Selection } from 'd3-selection';
import { scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale';

const dataTest = [
    {
        name: 'Oct30',
        number: 8000
    },
    {
        name: 'Oct29',
        number: 2000
    },
    {
        name: 'Oct28',
        number: 600
    },
    {
        name: 'Oct27',
        number: 3005
    }
]

const Barchart: React.FC = () => {

    const ref = useRef<SVGSVGElement | null>(null);
    const [selection, setSelection] = useState< null | Selection<SVGSVGElement | null, unknown, null, undefined>>(null);

    const y = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10000])
        .range([0, 400])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!selection){
            setSelection(select(ref.current))
        } else {

            console.log("y(0) ", y(0));
            console.log("y(0) ", y(2305));  // What happens as a test

// selection is where typescript is showing the error
            selection 
                .selectAll('rect')
                .data(dataTest)
                .enter()
                .append('rect')
                .attr('width', 100)
                .attr('x', (_, i) => i * 100)
                .attr('fill', 'orange')
                .attr('height', d => y(d.number)); // <the y() seems to be the problem.
        }
    }, [selection])
    return (
        <div> 
                <svg ref={ref} width={800} height={400} />
        </div>
    );
};


}
export default Barchart;
```

Here is the typescript error:

> Given a value from the domain, returns the corresponding value from the range, subject to interpolation, if any. If the given value is outside the domain, and clamping is not enabled, the mapping may be extrapolated such that the returned value is outside the range. Note: The interpolation function applied by the scale may change the output type from the range type as part of the interpolation. @param value — A numeric value from the domain.

Continued:

> No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 4, '(name: string, value: null): Selection<SVGRectElement, { name: string; number: number; }, SVGSVGElement | null, unknown>', gave the following error. Argument of type '(this: SVGRectElement, d: { name: string; number: number; }) => number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'. Overload 2 of 4, '(name: string, value: string | number | boolean): Selection<SVGRectElement, { name: string; number: number; }, SVGSVGElement | null, unknown>', gave the following error.

I have tried to change:

```
.attr('height', d => y(d.number))
```

to

```
.attr('height', d => d.number)
```

there were no errors. My guess is on this line "const y = scaleLinear()" I need to set something. Any help would be appreciated.

no luck making this change:

```
    let y = scaleLinear<number>()
        .domain([0, 10000])
        .range([0, 400])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `scaleLinear()` does not return a value 100% of the time.  In the definition for the `ScaleLinear` type, you can see that it can return either a `number` or `undefined`.

```
const y: ScaleLinear
(value: NumberValue) => number | undefined
```

But when you go to set the attribute 'height' on you SVG selection, the value you are setting **must** be a `number`.  It cannot be `undefined`.

The fix is easy.  We provide a fallback `number` to be used as the height if `y(d.number)` returns `undefined`.  Here I am using 0.

```
.attr('height', d => y(d.number) || 0 );
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGbZFIDKMKMSFxAoqaUhnAL5ylQQhwA5FFQZBAbgCwAKFCRYuOMQA27LHCpJVGYBAB2XHnwGCAJgGYAtCrW69EmXOjw8hNClUAZYHtRRDvPxCFtbuqg7SMmj6hPCmdCgAKkixcAC8cADaMnC5uDl5hXooIEgAXEIA8hjmAAyCmAWFuXr4IABGSFAVABy1-U1cjdKFOINFJeVVGABMAJwN43mtHV0VM-21g5zDo0stkxWC1TAzPYsjzS1tnd1wAGwDl7k7g2PPzcWlRyczAOwXK7XVZ3Oq1ACs2xkAF0ZFEYvAAEIoKBoAAWKJgFWQ6BgADoAGIAYXScAAFABKdIAPnykQ%200T0qREpFJlDIAB4qAA1ADiPN5TFUpT08AAPnBWsplNSyVLlBSpAyEVkbDp9NhiDBNNoYHZoWziDQ6EgOZL8NK4BKdbZ9Fy%20QKhUgReLzdKKHoANZ6CAAdz02HlHtMSFIPiQpmpsvlirhyqZ8AAnqS3B4kN5fCjKfs4HjTPwUD4yZlatgAIybWrQik5vFQFB6ADmSGLpbgABZ%20tXBoNKCw2BgyZSaXSgXBgKQyQBCNV6-QU95jwpam3qvRk2dkll4tD4KAiUUUmsfQrcLTEOk5wqMwgQVR45QQRtkgBEibJtSpL%20w78-sZPQI3neSAPk%20r6-l%20P5kjMdTgke4i5AA9IhcAAOoYvAGJgGASBMnAKCEPhcD0LEcZLnks52FeQJ4rOACC0pksIaiCMe5FXHmCRkvEtDJLEbHsYUeK4fQUDZgB5F4ig2G4aYTEiGIAmCbkUkwDAYmCL6wCmDAaINHAFaftRHF0OpTEAB76WSAD62DAFSaS0sAcAAFQGf0SnKapZmCGG0r6YI0ANs2rHGc03kaWiSDAI2aIwPppgju%20ph4istxUmKEq1HA-5jpw2zYJklH6N2HwiDAe4GGSOYcqYwAAG60mFhQcoQ9WNnALJpDgLLcFpOlot1fS1NwUUxXF3WdiNcCIdSNWIXVjWDP%20nBKkAA)