# D3 fill for a horizontal stacked bar chart in Angular with typeScript: .attr("fill", ..) gets error "No overload matches this call" in VSC

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a stacked horizontal bar chart in d3 by following the code [here](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/0aedd5f3fb8b099e3e10690bd38bd458).

I've created a minimal reproduction of the work I have so far on stackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nkr3d1?file=src/app/d3.service.ts).

Although I'm not getting the error in stackBlitz's linter, it occurs in this line on Visual Studio Code:

```
.attr("fill", (d) => {
            const colorKey = get(d, "key");
            console.log("deleteMe colorKey is: ");
            console.log(colorKey);
            const targetColor = color(colorKey) ? color(colorKey) : "#e41a1c";
            console.log("deleteMe targetColor is: ");
            console.log(targetColor);
            return targetColor;
          })
```

The full error that I'm getting reads:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 4, '(name: string,
> value: null): Selection<SVGGElement, Series<{ [key: string]: number;
> }, string>, SVGGElement, unknown>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(this: SVGGElement, d: Series<{ [key: string]: number; }, string>) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'null'.   Overload 2 of 4, '(name: string, value: string | number |
> boolean): Selection<SVGGElement, Series<{ [key: string]: number; },
> string>, SVGGElement, unknown>', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(this: SVGGElement, d: Series<{ [key: string]: number; }, string>) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string | number | boolean'.
> Type '(this: SVGGElement, d: Series<{ [key: string]: number; }, string>) => unknown' is not assignable to type 'true'.   Overload 3 of
> 4, '(name: string, value: ValueFn<SVGGElement, Series<{ [key: string]:
> number; }, string>, string | number | boolean>):
> Selection<SVGGElement, Series<...>, SVGGElement, unknown>', gave the
> following error.
> Argument of type '(this: SVGGElement, d: Series<{ [key: string]: number; }, string>) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'ValueFn<SVGGElement, Series<{ [key: string]: number; }, string>,
> string | number | boolean>'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'true'.ts(2769)

I found [this related issue on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64471570/react-typescript-d3js-getting-a-no-overload-matches-this-call) (many other related posts were in React, and they mostly had to do with extraneous props being provided to components), so I made sure that my anonymous function returned a hex color no matter what, but that did not solve the problem. Unfortunately, I don't quite understand the various override signatures for the d3.attr("fill",...) error above, so I'd love

1. A solution to that override issue and, if possible,
2. An explanation (or link to one) about what, specifically, those signatures mean for .attr("fill",...).
3. Any additional help getting the horizontal stacked barchart displaying horizontally stacked bars would be extremely welcome.

Regarding the latter (#2 above), I have looked a little bit into some documentation [here](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/custom_color.html) and pretty much seen the same syntax there:

```
svg.selectAll(".firstrow").data(data).enter().append("circle").attr("cx", function(d,i){return 30 + i*60}).attr("cy", 50).attr("r", 19).attr("fill", function(d){return myColor(d) })
```

This is not typeScript, and I'm not sure how to make it typeScript friendly...

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Print `console.log(typeof  targetColor);` before `return targetColor;` What do you see in the console?

Comment: It says it's a string.

Comment: If you replace entire block `.attr('fill', d => { ... })` with `.attr('fill', '#e41a1c')`, do you still get the same Typescript error?

Comment: Nope. The error goes away.

Comment: So the error is triggered by either `get()` or `color()` uses. Can you post their definitions?

Comment: Hi, @Michael Rovinsky. The whole code is available https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nkr3d1?file=src/app/d3.service.ts.
get is from lodash. color is:
 const color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#e41a1c', '#377eb8']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `get` may return `any` value, its result should be strongly typed:

```
.attr("fill", (d) => {
  const colorKey = String(get(d, "key"));
  return color(colorKey) ?? "#e41a1c";
})
```

Comment: I was also able to solve the problem by clarifying the type of scaleOrdinal... As in, 
const color = d3
          .scaleOrdinal<string>()
          .range(["#e41a1c", "#377eb8"]);